# Problem with zipping more than 2 observable sequences

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reactive

I am looking for an information why `Zip` operator does not work with more than 2 observable streams:

```
var stream1 = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
        {
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });

        var stream2 = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
        {
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });

        var stream3 = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
        {
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });

        var stream4 = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
        {
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });

        var stream6 = stream1.Zip(stream2, stream3, stream4, (a, b, c, d) =>
        {
            return a + b + c + d;
        });

        var i = stream6.ToTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The error I receive is:

> Sequence contains no elements

The `Zip` operator works fine when I am zipping only two sequences tho.

Below I pasted stack trace:

```
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   in ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) w Path\Program.cs:line 58
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace along with the applicable line numbers, so we can see where the error is actually coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the original post and pasted stack trace.

Comment: Just as a side-note, which is not related to your issue, you should always consider returning a `Disposable.Empty` in a `Create` as a bad design as it can easily create race conditions and/or dead-locks.. There's almost always a way to achieve what you want by using the standard operators.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a bug, or at best shoddy design. To make things simpler:

```
var stream = Observable.Return(1);

var result2 = await stream.Zip(stream, (a, b) => (a, b));
var result3 = await stream.Zip(stream, stream, (a, b, c) => (a, b, c));

Console.WriteLine($"result2 = {result2}");
Console.WriteLine($"result3 = {result3}");
```

`result2` works, because the zip yields a value. The `result3` observable isn't yielding a value, so the await fails. However, it should yield a value. Here's the documentation on that overload:

> Merges the specified observable sequences into one observable sequence by using the selector function whenever all of the observable sequences have produced an element at a corresponding index.

Since they all yielded a value at index 0, you should see a value. So... bug.

Interestingly, if you re-define `stream` as such:

```
var stream = Observable.Return(1).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15));
```

...then both work. Bug probably relates to some race condition.

I think the pair-wise function (with 2 observables) is older and better tested then the n-wise overloads.

Comment: Thank you for double checking my case, I spent the whole evening trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I will try to downgrade System.Reactive as I am almost sure that I used the n-wise overloads of Zip operator in past.

Comment: Just to leave the summary of my case, it looks that bug appeared in version 4.1.0 of System.Reactive. I downgraded this library to 4.0.0 and works fine. Thank you all for help.

Comment: @user3659914 it seems that in version 4.4.1 the bug has been fixed ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IJoLK5)).